# puppeteer: Get base64 encoded image without separate download

Tags: node.js, uri, puppeteer

On a page that does not support downloading images or opening them in new tab, I can use the Chrome Developer (Tools->Network) to right click the image and do "copy image as URI".

Is it possible to do the same with puppeteer?

I tried to use few Node.js modules that are intended to convert an image to its base64 representation but they all seem to download the image and then return base64 representation.

Comment: Can't you get the src of the HTML image element?

Comment: Yes, but I can't download it, can't redirect to http of that image. Page that host image reports error when trying to save or open in new tab, I tried to get URI in puppeteer but base64 I get is encoded error from page, not image.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`response.buffer()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#responsebuffer) to get the buffer of a resource. You can then turn the buffer into a base64-encoded string by using [`buffer.toString('base64')`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).

**Code Sample**

The following example goes to the `google.com` website, waits for the first PNG resource and then prints its base64-encoded image.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const [response] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes('.png')),
        page.goto('https://www.google.com/')
    ]);
    const buffer = await response.buffer();
    console.log('data:image/png;base64,' + buffer.toString('base64'));

    await browser.close();
})();
```

This code sample waits for a single resource. Alternatively, you could listen to the [`response`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#event-response) event to download multiple images in the same way.

Answer (score 32):

another solution is:

```js
const base64 = await page.screenshot({ encoding: "base64" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me

```
  let screenshot = await page.screenshot({ encoding: "base64" }).then(function(data){
            let base64Encode = `data:image/png;base64,${data}`;
            return base64Encode;
    });
```

you can use that in addcontext - it will add in mochareport

```
addContext(this, {
    title: 'screenshot ',
    value: global.backEndData.contactCountTotalImage,
  });
```